# displaying data ng-repeat from $scope.items query not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-apicontroller

I do not know what is wrong, **ng-repeat** is not
populating the information on my div, please look at the following
and advice where I have gone wrong

**app.js**

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ["ngRoute", "ngResource"]);
mainApp.factory('EventListFactory',['$resource', EventListFactory]);
mainApp.controller('EventListCtrl', ['$scope','EventListFactory', EventListCtrl]);
var configFunction = function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Register', {
            templateUrl: 'routesDemo/Register'
        })
        .when('/UpdateProfile', {
            templateUrl: 'routesDemo/UpdateProfile'
        })
        .when('/Events', {
            templateUrl: 'routesDemo/Events', 
            controller: EventListCtrl,
        })
        .when('/routeThree', {
            templateUrl: 'routesDemo/three'
        });
}
configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
mainApp.config(configFunction);
```

**EventListFactory.js**

```
var EventListFactory = function ($resource, $location) {

        var baseUrl = "";
        if (window.location.hostname == 'localhost') {
            baseUrl = "http://localhost:52182/api/Events/GetEvents/";
        }
        else
        {
            var deployAt = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href);
            baseUrl = deployAt + "/api/Events/GetEvents";
        }

        var respone = $resource(baseUrl, null, { query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true, url: baseUrl }, get: { method: 'GET', url: baseUrl } });
        console.log("api json at :" + baseUrl);
        var records = respone.query();
        console.log(records);
        return records;
}
```

***EventListController.js***

```
var EventListCtrl = function ($scope, EventListFactory) {
    $scope.Message = 'I work';
    $scope.items = EventListFactory;
};

EventListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

**in the html:**

```
<div id="listView" >
    <h1 class="form-signin-heading">For real {{Message}}</h1>
    <div ng-controller="EventListCtrl">
        <p class="form-signin-heading">Populated Data</p>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items ">
            <span class="control-label">Heading : </span> {{item.Heading}}
            <br/>
            <span class="control-label">Event Date : </span> {{item.EventDate}}
            <br/>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**running the site:**

[image]

**api call from browser:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the code for ng-repeat is correct, but your items is an empty array so nothing gets displayed.

From the screenshots it appears that `records` in `EventListFactory.js` does not return an array but a promise.

In `EventListController.js` instead of

> $scope.items = EventListFactory;

Try something like:

```
var promise = EventListFactory;
promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.items = data;
})
```

Comment: It is complaining with 'then' undefined

Comment: can you tell me what does console.log(promise) displays?